# Need to remove text between html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some content in HTML format and i want to remove Comments Example between the tags.

For eg: Content is like

```
 <p dir="ltr" id="_13" style="margin-left: 0px; "><span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: times new roman,times; ">Time span values shall allow creation or retrieval using any of the following units:<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Days<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Hours<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Minutes<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Seconds<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Milliseconds<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Microseconds</span><br><br><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: times new roman,times; "><b><i>Comments</i></b></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: times new roman,times; "><i> Example</i></span></p>
```

I want to specifically remove Comments Example. I can fetch it in two separate variables, but basically where they are present consecutively there only it should be removed.

Expected result will be:

```
<p dir="ltr" id="_13" style="margin-left: 0px; "><span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: times new roman,times; ">Time span values shall allow creation or retrieval using any of the following units:<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Days<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Hours<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Minutes<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Seconds<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Milliseconds<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Microseconds</span><br><br><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: times new roman,times; "><b><i></i></b></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: times new roman,times; "><i></i></span></p>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: So you want to leave the `<i>` elements in the DOM, but just remove their content?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element using `span:eq()`, and then just use `text()`:

```js
$('#_13').find('span:eq(1) i').text('');
$('#_13').find('span:eq(2) i').text('');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p dir="ltr" id="_13">
    <span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: times new roman,times;">
        Time span values shall allow creation or retrieval using any of the following units:<br><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Days<br><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Hours<br><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Minutes<br><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Seconds<br><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Milliseconds<br><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Microseconds
    </span><br><br>
    <span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: times new roman,times;"><b><i>Comments</i></b></span>
    <span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: times new roman,times; "><i>Example</i></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Id will not be specific in my case. Any other way without using id.

Comment: @VishakhaKansal use the same technique as the `span` selector above.

Comment: content may not be necessarily in <i> tag. I specifically want to search for text Comments Example and remove it. But since it has html tags in between so i am not able traverse this string. Also, i cant remove html tags as is because it may mess with formating. Any other way could you please suggest.